# How to make VS2008 auto insert indent for F#?

Tags: f#

Just as my title . I want my VS to auto indent for me like in VBNET . Please help.

Comment: Have you tried cntrl k, cntrl f? I found that here, but haven't tried it yet. http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Comment: VS2017 now has auto-indentation for F#. Just type `let x = ` and Enter and you'll see. Same for bracketet expressions like lists, computation expressions, and record expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the F# language integration doesn't support this feature.

Also, automatic formatting is not as useful in F# as it is in Visual Basic. In VB, the formatting is not really important (so you can write code with crazy indentation and the formatter can fix it). In F#, the indenation (partly) determines what code means, so you need to write correctly indented code (although I agree that the automatic formatting could make the code more consistent).

In principle it should be possible to implement this feature as a Visual Studio plugin using the open source release of F#. There is a similar plugin that adds [colors for nested expressions](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/f-source-code-structural-colorizer-available/) by Brian, so that could be used as an inspiration, but it's *definitely* not something I could write in the answer box :-).

Comment: So no way to make it auto - indent ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the indentation-sensitive syntax that F# inherited from languages like Haskell makes it impossible to auto-indent. This is actually my only major gripe with the F# language because, in addition to making it impossible to implement professional tools like auto-indenters, it renders programs fragile in the absence of correct indentation which means an accidental change in whitespace can silently corrupt a program and cut-and-paste (e.g. from blogs) is prone to breaking or corrupting programs. F# almost always screws up if you feed it OCaml code, partly because it cannot handle tabs.

The damn crying shame is that OCaml already got this right by providing a concise unambiguous syntax and powerful tools. For example, you can autoindent any definition by pressing ALT+Q in Emacs. This makes it much easier to manipulate OCaml code and can be an enormous time saver. I often find myself trawling through F# code trying to reindent it by hand, having to read the code in detail and understand the algorithm just to indent it is seriously frustrating. Having done this many times, I can also state quite confidently that the verbosity savings of the `#light` syntax are insignificant. In fact, F# is almost always more verbose than OCaml in practice.

Comment: light mode just make thing harder to recognize. :(

Comment: F# now has auto-indentation in its recent versions, but it is still improving. See for instance: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/3313. In VS2017 it is now a much more natural typing experience (also when brackets are not involved), while not perfect yet, for me I notice I make much less indentation mistakes now.

Comment: @Abel: You mean F# now suggests one possible indentation for a new line? I'm referring to the ability to unambiguously autoindent code from unindented or wrongly-indented code which is now impossible with F#'s modern indentation-sensitive syntax.

Comment: Re-indent  wrongly indented code, say on copy / paste, no, that isn't supported and I think it may even be impossible (except perhaps for the trivial cases). I meant auto-indent while typing, which has now become 'smart' and works rather smooth in my experience (though currently only on nightlies)

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to pour cold water all over this question.  In principle, it's impossible to provide an auto-formatter for a whitespace-significant language.

(Pragmatically, you could add a few small niceties to the editor, e.g. if you type a line of code that starts with `if` and ends with the matching `then` and press enter, the editor could get smart and also insert the next indent so you don't also have to press tab.  But this is a far cry from auto-formatting, which I think would be wrong-headed to even attempt.)

Comment: Would be great if you guys could support the indentation-insensitive syntax and add tooling for it, e.g. autoindent in VS.